# PWA and the protocol_handler - manifest or javascript and why?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, manifest, url-scheme

here are some demo links i could not get working, therefore the Q & A below:

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MSEdgeExplainers/blob/main/URLProtocolHandler/explainer.md

https://protocol-handler.glitch.me/

I'm trying to open the PWA from a browser link, if the PWA is installed. I read about the "protocol_handler" and the two methods of installing the desired urlscheme.

Namely using JavaScript or the manifest file.

In these demo links above, the urlscheme contains a prefix "web+" is this a must for a pwa or can i just have a urlscheme like "appname://" instead of "web+appname://"  ?

which of these methods to install the url protocol is the preferred method or when will i use either of them?

UPDATE:
I read some more information regarding the manifest file and the start_url and scope of the PWA.

In my current manifest file i have the default values:
start_url : index.html;
and
scope: '/';

But now i have read that one can set the values to the following:
start_url: 'https://thedesireddomane.com/index.html'
and
scope: 'https://thedesireddomane.com/'

and if i use the domain names, then when ever a link is clicked and contains any part of the domain name, the PWA will open? Is this true? or do i need the url_protocol? and why?

Its a very limited topic and the information available is not definitive at all.

Comment: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223)

Comment: Thank you, I've noted your response. Is it not related to one topic though? PWA and the protocol_handler - manifest or JavaScript and why?